# Basic numpy Adam implementation

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, forward

since I am trying to understand the mechanisms onto which different neural network models are based, I decided to implement an Adam Optimizer using only numpy, without additional frameworks. 
When I shuffle the dataset as

```
def shuffling(X_Train, Y_Train, m, minibatch_size):
  permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
  shuffled_X = X_Train[:, permutation]
  shuffled_Y = Y_Train[:, permutation]
  n_comp_minibatches = math.floor(m / minibatch_size)+1
  minibatches = [(shuffled_X[:,i*minibatch_size:(i+1)*minibatch_size],
                 shuffled_Y[:,i*minibatch_size:(i+1)*minibatch_size])
                 for i in range(n_comp_minibatches)]

  return minibatches
```

and I later proceed to implement model according to the following algorithm

```
def AdamModel(X_Train, Y_Train, lay_size, learning_rate, minibatch_size, 
beta1, beta2, epsilon, n_epoch, print_cost=False):
  #Implements the complete model
  #Incudes shuffling of minibatches at each epoch
  L=len(lay_size)
  costs=[]
  t=0             #Initialize the counter for Adam update +1 at each epoch
  m=X_Train.shape[1]

  #Initialization of parameters
  parameters = initialize_parameters(lay_size)

  #Initialization of v, s for Adam
  v, s = initialize_Adam(parameters)

  #iterates the procedure for n_epoch
  for n in range(n_epoch):
     #Permutation of X_Train, Y_Train and creation of minibatches
     minibatches = shuffling(X_Train, Y_Train, m, minibatch_size)

     #Iterate the forward-backward procedure for each minibatch
     for minibatch in minibatches:

        #Unpacking of minibatch content
        (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch

        #Forward-prop for the minibatch
        AL, caches = L_lay_forw(minibatch_X, parameters)          <---

        #Computes the cost associated to the output of the minibatch
        cost = compute_cost(AL, minibatch_Y)

        #Computation of gradients
        grads = L_lay_back(minibatch_Y, AL, caches)

        #Parameters updating procedure
        t +=1
        parameters = upd_para_adam(parameters, grads, v, s, t, 
                     learning_rate, beta1, beta2, epsilon)

    if print_cost and n%20==0:
        print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" %(n, cost))
    if print_cost and n%20==0:
        costs.append(cost)

#Plot the graph related to the learning instance
plt.plot(costs)
plt.ylabel("Cost")
plt.xlabel("Epoch (per twentieth)")
plt.title("Learning rate :"+str(learning_rate))
plt.show()

return parameters
```

I get the following error - "Traceback: tuple indeces must be integer or slices, not str" - for "AL, caches = L_lay_forw(minibatch_X, parameters)  --> A, cache = linear_act_forward(A_prev, parameters["W"+str(l)], parameters["b"+str(l)], act)"  but I am not able to understand why.

```
def L_lay_forw(X, parameters):
  #Iterates the linear_act_forward process across the entire architecture
  #stores all the "cache" in a caches list
  #Stores all the activations in a A_l list
  caches=[]
  A_l=[]
  L=len(parameters)//2
  A=X
  for l in range(1,L+1):
    A_prev=A
    if l!=L:
        act="ReLu"
    elif l==L:
        act="Softmax"
    A, cache = linear_act_forward(A_prev, parameters["W"+str(l)], 
       parameters["b"+str(l)], act)
    caches.append(cache)
    A_l.append(A)
  AL= A
```

Specifically, I can't define which of the parameters behaves as an object requiring tuple indexing. Is anybody able to help me out?